# Matrix Undefined Offset

Tags: php, matrix, undefined, offset

I am receiving following error in php

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplikasijadwal07\index.php on line 80
```

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplikasijadwal07\index.php on line 80

Here is the code

```
<?php
            $i=1;
            while($slot_jam = mysql_fetch_array($jam)){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="time" align="center">';
            echo $slot_jam['jam'];
            echo '</td>';

            if($i==5 || $i==8 || $i==12){
                    $j=1;
                    while ($j<=7)
                    {
                      $M[$i][$j]='<div align="center">IST</div>';
                      $j=$j+1;
                    }
            }

                $j=1;
                while($j<=6){
                    if($M[$i][$j] == ''){        //LINE 80
                        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<td class="isi">'.$M[$i][$j].'</td>';
                    }
                $j=$j+1;
                }
            echo '</tr>';
            $i=$i+1;
            }
        ?>
```

This code works as I want, but I get error notice undefined offset

Comment: A character in a string will never equal the empty string; the reason it works is because dereferencing an empty string yields an empty string.

Comment: you accessing of empty array, and it will be give warning `offset`. check first with `empty()` function ` :  `while($j<=6){ if(!empty($M[$i][$j]) { /*bla bla*/}}`